# Unable to install programs on windows 8

Tags: windows-installer

I have various programs installed on win8 that when I try to install run windows installer and it failes with some strange error about not being able to access C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi (excerpet from windows installer log below)

any idea how to fix this?

```
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:674]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:674]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:736]: MSI_LUA: Credential Request return = 0x0
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:736]: MSI_LUA: Elevated credential consent provided. Install will run elevated
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:736]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPackageCertificate 
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:736]: BeginTransaction: Locking Server
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:736]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:736]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:752]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:752]: Server not locked: locking for product {D96E4F17-2635-4CBD-9308-F99228929C41}
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:19:752]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287037 
    Info 2835.The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog SetupError.
    Error 2203.Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi. Cannot open database file. System error -2147287037.
    MSI (s) (0C:80) [16:32:20:783]: Product: RamDisk Plus 11.8 -- Error 2203.Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi. Cannot open database file. System error -2147287037.

    Action ended 16:32:20: InstallInitialize. Return value 3.
    Action ended 16:32:20: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

...

```
    === Logging stopped: 30/05/2013  16:32:21 ===
    MSI (c) (10:B8) [16:32:21:783]: Note: 1: 1729 
    MSI (c) (10:B8) [16:32:21:783]: Product: RamDisk Plus 11.8 -- Configuration failed.

    MSI (c) (10:B8) [16:32:21:783]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: RamDisk Plus 11.8. Product Version: 11.8.1186. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SuperSpeed LLC. Reconfiguration success or error status: 1603.

    MSI (c) (10:B8) [16:32:21:783]: Grabbed execution mutex.
    MSI (c) (10:B8) [16:32:21:783]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
    MSI (c) (10:B8) [16:32:21:783]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
    === Verbose logging stopped: 30/05/2013  16:32:21 ===
```

Comment: Do other installers work?

Comment: Does [this FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall) help?

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by Karan in the comment above, I used Microsoft [FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall)